# Remove event listener with the new library

Tags: dart

How do i remove a listener for an event I've previously registered to with the new dart library?

I'm using this to listen for events with the new library:

```
element.onMouseMove.listen
```

What is the equivalent version of this?

```
element.on.mouseMove.remove
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`element.onMouseMove.listen(...)` returns a [StreamSubscription](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/StreamSubscription.html). Simply call its [cancel()](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/StreamSubscription.html#cancel) method to stop receiving events.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to Alexandre's answer, a concrete example in code would look like this:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  var listener = (e) => print("Moved");

  var element = query("#text");
  var streamsub = element.onMouseMove.listen(listener); // <--- add the listener

  var reverseText= (Event event) {
    var text = query("#text").text;
    var buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      buffer.add(text[i]);
    }
    query("#text").text = buffer.toString();

    streamsub.cancel(); // <----   stop listening
  };

  element
    ..text = "Click me!"
    ..onClick.listen(reverseText);    
}
```

This prints "Moved" when you move the mouse over the "Click Me!" text (from the standard dart sample).  When clicked, it stops.