# How do I stop listening to HTML events, in Dart?

Tags: dart

I am listening for click events like this:

```
element.onClick.listen((e) => doCoolStuff());
```

How do I stop listening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove event listener with the new library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476738/remove-event-listener-with-the-new-library)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `onClick` returns a [StreamSubscription](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/StreamSubscription.html), you can `cancel()` it to stop receiving events.

Here is an example:

```
import 'dart:async';

// ...

var subscription = element.onClick.listen((e) => doCoolStuff());
// later
subscription.cancel();
```