# Remove onclick event from ButtonElement

Tags: dart

I added this before. myBtn.onClick.listen((_){//some code});

Now I want to remove the event from the button, so:

How do you remove the onClick event from a ButtonElement by code? I can't find an obvious way to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14476980/2744839

Answer (score 4):

The .listen() returns a subscription. Which you could store in a var and call .cancel() on.

Comment: What if you need to cancel it as soon as the element is clicked.
My specific use case is where you have an onClick of an element and in it you check some conditions and if the conditions are correct, remove the onClick event